How come Sauron was so unconvincing before?
In The Lord of the Rings: The Rings of Power Season 2, Episode 1, we see Sauron before he is

 killed by Adar and the Orcs.

Despite being the primary enemy of the Elves at this time, he seems surprisingly ineffective at controlling the Orcs. He attempts to persuade them to make him their king, but his performance is lackluster, and none of the Orcs seem moved by it.
This is particularly surprising because, at the end of Season 1, we saw Sauron interact with

 Galadriel

in a much more convincing manner. He was persuasive, used magic, and appeared more "cool" and formidable overall.
Given Sauron's reputation and abilities, why was he so ineffective at persuading the Orcs in this instance?

It's The Rings of Power. What do you expect?

Looks like he had some sort of power-up…

One Ring to rule them all?

One might perhaps assume that the writers (who are actual professional writers) are not complete idiots and had a plan. Also, since it's an adaptation, trying to answer using the first age Silmarillion Sauron (who was bested by a dog and a half-elf/malf-Maia maiden btw, and ran off and was never heard of for hundreds of years) doesn't really help.

@DavidRoberts Sauron was bested by a dog that was destined to be killed by the greatest wolf. Sauron had too much confidence, he was played by Fate - That's far from delivering a dumb speech and kneeling in front of an Orc to be crowned.

@Eugene well, we all know that "power levels" aren't a thing in Tolkien. If Fingolfin can wound Morgoth, if Lúthien can sing all of Angband to sleep, if Elendil and Gil-galad can 'kill' Sauron, then a corrupted Elf who appears to be older than all of Finwë's children, using an item of great power, can presumably do a bit of damage. Yes it's overconfidence. Sauron was trying to pull the "what they most fear" lever on the orcs, as the show explicitly set up in S1 and also reinforced this season, but he misjudged Adar. A single regular orc, or arguably a whole bunch, wouldn't achieve much.

The question to ask is if the show is showing is a consistent arc for the character it has developed, and that seems to me to be what this site is for, not for editorialising one's own opinion on the quality of the show. If the latter was what happened here, then I'm sure literally every single question could be flooded with comments pointing out weaknesses, perceived or otherwise, in writing etc in any given piece of media. Why not try to actually analyse the story on-screen?

@DavidRoberts We need to assume the writing is reasonable, self-consistent, in order to answer with reason, but so far the show as a whole is an inconsistent mess. Even putting the books aside, Sauron's entire plan in the show still makes no sense, as of yet. I cannot see anyone come up with an answer that makes sense. In the 1st ep of S1, we get a flashback of Sauron wearing a crown that's similar enough to this one, towering above his minions. That scene is totally thrown away.

I know the show is not perfect, but answering a question (albeit in a comment) with "lol, the show is inconsistent! 0/10 would not recommend" doesn't help the person who asks the question. Commenting with "what do expect from [show]?", with the implication that it has such a poor reputation no one needs explain why the question doesn't deserve a considered answer, really doesn't help anyone.

@DavidRoberts Pointing out that this show is too inconsistent to make sense of is probably one of the most helpful things that can be said about this show.

@Eugene well, I hope you find things more enjoyable to spend time doing than inflicting thinking about RoP on yourself. I certainly don't engage in discussion with media I don't enjoy because my time is too limited to waste it like that :-) (Too much Tolkien to read, among other things!)

@DavidRoberts I am trying to help anyone who's expecting an answer as much as you think you are, and I am enjoying my time.


his performance is lackluster, and none of the Orcs seem moved by it.

On the contrary, they look rather moved by Sauron's threats that they need him because other races will treat them like scum etc. But he takes it a step too far with the "many of you will die... and that's a risk I'm willing to take" line—Adar as we know from S1 is hyperdedicated to providing for and protecting those he considers his children (and lots of them probably are his literal descendants). Since the crown is Morgoth's, refashioned to fit Sauron, it is apparently an object imbued with some great power. We find out this is the Iron Crown with a "some say" moment in Ep 6, where Adar lampshades the non-continuity with the story told in the 1977 Silmarillion—outside the rights the show has licensed—where we are told it is beaten into a collar for Morgoth who is then cast into the Void.
That Orcs are internally rebellious against Sauron is established clearly in Lord of the Rings: we even have the tracker Orc in Mordor who is willing to kill the soldier he is with who threatens to report him to their superiors. It's just that Sauron by this stage has established a complete culture of control and hierarchy. Post the (unnamed) War of Wrath in the show the evil had been deemed to have been eliminated. So there can't have been any cohesive organisation, at least, none that was obvious. Sauron clearly had enough organisation to set up this commencement of what he thought would be his ascent to power. If we allow ourselves a moment from the Silmarillion, the last we saw of Sauron in the First Age is running away injured as he'd surrendered to Lúthien rather than have his fana killed and have to face Morgoth after such a defeat. Hardly the act of a dominant and confident character.
In the Silmarillion text, the next we hear of him is the near-repentance to Eönwë, but again the unwillingness to face the Valar in judgement when presented the opportunity to own up to his rebellion. This is roughly where the show seems to be picking up, without addressing either of these latter two points (see again: rights issues). The showrunners have said they wanted to play on the "was he truly repentant?" question in season 1—the way things are played it is deliberately ambiguous. From a S2 viewpoint he is definitely no longer repentant, even if he was. But was he ever? Meeting Diarmuid while wandering Middle-earth in the guise of Halbrand and being presented with a chance to start a new life is the closest it seems, but that is short-lived.
But to return to the question: Ep1 of S1 calls him Morgoth's servant (in a scene that seems to have been added after test screenings, and IMO not a good choice, but done to help movie-only viewers visually recognise who is being spoken about). At the start of Ep1 of S2, he's been suddenly elevated to the top job, so to speak. He starts by pulling the trick that he employs later in the show's timeline: try to play on the fears of someone or a group of people, and offer them something they want/need. One orc tries to take matters into his own hands and is brutally murdered. None of the other orcs is willing to do anything after that. But Adar is literally handed the tool with which he can decide to protect his children from exploitation as Sauron's explanation lets slip. This time it's a truth too far. Once Sauron is attacked with the crown, he is debilitated enough that the crowd of orcs can a) be emboldened to attack him and b) start to actual damage to his body.
At the end of S1, Sauron has had reflection time, is dealing with one person in Galadriel, not a crowd, and has dealt with her by not trying to intimidate her, but manipulate by giving her what she wants. This proves to be a much more effective method. He's also leveraging what is probably ósanwë, since she has been so open with him, and was extremely receptive to accepting his help - we get a reference to this in S2 when Gil-galad is talking with Galadriel and how she now has shut Sauron out.
I have only watched the episodes once, and I'm working from memory and don't have to a hand electronic version of the script to quote exactly, so please forgive imprecision.
Is this in perfect continuity with season 1? Not exactly. S2 has had some soft reboot aspects. Is it continuity with various source texts? In subtle ways, yes, and in some unsubtle ways, no. I imagine the show has to make some "this is a story that is legally distinct" adaptation choices, aside from trying to turn sketchy Second Age material into an actual dramatic portrayal.

I don't think the question is about whether Sauron can be killed like that. Sauron is not dominant in between Huan's teeth, and that's irrelevant. If you are taking the books into account, Sauron should appear dominant over regular orcs. He doesn't need to deliver a speech to some orcs, like a senator, and that speech is plain awful. I don't interpret those growls as the Orcs being moved, rather angered by the speech, so angered one of them stabs him.

One can be moved negatively as well as positively.... I will have to disengage from this conversation now, I have other things I should have rather been doing.

Adar might be secretly working with Sauron, maybe not knowingly, and the assassination has been part of Sauron's plan all along. He did all that do get into Galadriel's heart, and he had been planning since before he killed Finrod
Sauron killed Finrod, branded him to get to Galadriel. Then he played a changed person, a victim from betrayal who wanted another life in peace, and somehow he had Galadriel believe "Sauron lives because of you", even though we can't see that from the plot - on the contrary Galadriel lives because of Sauron. Anyway he lets guilt devour Galadriel's mind.
But at least Sauron had been dead, and Galadriel knew that because Adar told her so.

This has been one of the popular theories that cannot be proven or debunked yet. But recent episode provides us more evidence.
It's been several days so I'm not putting the rest of the answer into a spoiler block. Just stop reading if you don't want any.
In episode 6 of S2, SOMEHOW:

Adar knows of the Three Rings, and what they are for, probably from the messengers who were probably killed by Adar.
Adar thinks with the Three Rings and the Crown he maybe able to kill Sauron for good, which means Adar knows how the Three Rings work, he may even know about mithril (otherwise how would he know all this).
Adar also suddenly knows Halbrand is Sauron.

We must assume either:

Adar is kind of an expert in Ring magic himself, thanks to the teaching of Sauron. In fact Saruon planned to craft the Rings before his assassination. Remember: Power over flesh, something something, and Adar has been part of that plan. It's unlikely something that Sauron told Adar as Halbrand. Because why would Adar just believe a mere human King in rags talking about magic rings killing Sauron?

or Adar made that up. He has no idea what those Rings can do, even though I think we can safely assume Galadriel will just believe Adar's theory for no reason.


More hints Adar is working with Sauron.

Adar suddenly has an oversized Orc army, we wonder where were they when Adar struggled to take a village of fifty people and five or so Elven guards.
When Galadriel warns Adar it's Sauron's plan, Adar won't listen.

Middle-earth is vast and it seems the Elves in the show can't even spot an army within leagues even with supersight, let alone other places in Eriador or east of the Misty Mountains.
There's no reason the Orcs had to hide an army from the Elves when they were trying to take the Southlands. Unless, maybe, Sauron was playing with the Elves, it was his army all along.
There are lots of speculations but our pro-writers leaves a lot of holes for the audience to fill, major events that happen off-screen. They will be likely never mentioned again in future episodes, so we can only speculate. Assuming these writers are pros and everything happens for a reason, this is the best I can come up with.
In episode 7 or 8 we may be able to see how Sauron get Adar's army, even if Adar is simply biting Sauron's bait, we still can't be 100% sure that the assassination wasn't part of Sauron's plan.

Adar's sadistic nature adds to the theory he's influenced by Sauron. There's a scene in S1 where he exposes an orc's arm to the sunlight and let it burn a little. He's not much of a caring father he claims to be.
